# Spring-Batch interferes with Apache Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-batch

I am using Spring-Batch V3.0.6 with Spring V4.2.4 and Apache Camel 2.16.2 and in my configuration each time a Spring batch job (JSR API) is stopping, it stops my Camel context! It could be because of my config that I will try to explain.

First of all I am using only the JSR API and not native Spring Batch API. To be able to call/use Spring bean inside the job definition (JSR XML) I configured Spring-Batch context loading a shared context (loaded by the ContextLoaderListener). In that shared context I defined the CamelContext via the Spring-Camel tags (to be able also to use Spring beans inside the camel routes easily).

When none jobs ran, we do not have any issue, the Camel routes are up and work perfectly. The problem starts as soon a job is started and stops. Indeed, it seems that when a job is starting is trying to start and when the jobs ends it stops the Camel context by send a 'ContextClosedEvent' that is processed by the CamelContext. From this moment Camel is up only when a job is running.

What can I modify in my configuration and/or code to make it work and let my Camel context up? I maybe configured the shared context wrongly.